# Core Data gradually increases memory

Tags: objective-c, core-data, memory-management, memory-leaks

When inserting object frequently [50-100] into Core Data, it gradually increase memory. I am using Xcode 7 and iOS 8.2

Sample code by which I tried to add data into core-data

```
- (BOOL)insertOrderItemData {

    BOOL success=NO;
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self managedObjectContext];
    OrderItems *orderItem = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"OrderItems" inManagedObjectContext:context];

    //...............
    //...............

    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error]) {
        //error handlgin
    } else {
        success=YES;
    }

    [context reset];

    return success;
}
```

**Any idea?**  How can I reduce the memory uses of the app?

Comment: Use instruments to see what's going on

Comment: Question is a bit unclear. By adding objects I would expect memory allocation to increase, where else would the new objects reside? Is the question that you think memory increase too much? If so, do as previous comment suggest and measure why. Is the issue that the memory do not get released if you remove the CoreData objects? That could be because they are not really released (yet) just marked for deletion. Also the managed object context maintains an undo stack that grows with each change. If you do not need that set the undo manager to `nil`.

Comment: when I insert into core data memory increases but when delete object from core data memory does not decreases.

Comment: What do you mean with "increase"? As @Wain said, you should verify it with Instruments, so in a very objective way. In addition, if you do a `reset` on a context, your context will be cleared. Can you provide a context on your saving? What type of model do you have? etc.